# How to create a shared_ptr concisely?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

How to make the statement shorter:

```
auto ptr = std::shared_ptr<CPoint>(new CPoint(x, y));
```

Please notice the `CPoint` appears twice. Can it be shorter?

like:

```
auto ptr = XXXX<CPoint>(x, y);
```

`XXXX` is a macro or anything. It should apply to any constructor with any parameters.

```
auto ptrA = XXXX<ClassA>(); // a shared_ptr to new ClassA()
auto ptrB = XXXX<ClassB>(a, b, c); // a shared_ptr to new ClassB(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could, and should, use function template [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

```
auto p = std::make_shared<CPoint>(x, y);
auto pA = std::make_shared<ClassA>(); // a shared_ptr to new ClassA()
auto pB = std::make_shared<ClassB>(a, b, c); // a shared_ptr to new ClassB(a, b, c)
```

To give it a different name, you can use a simple wrapper function:

```
template< class T, class... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> foo( Args&&... args )
{
  return std::make_shared<T>( std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

then

```
auto pB = foo<ClassB>(a, b, c);
```

Comment: How to typedef std:make_shared<T>, I want to make it shorter like: `auto p = $new<ClassB>(a, b,c)`?

Comment: @Zach `template <class T, class... Args>
auto snew(Args &&... args) {
    return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}`

Comment: @Quentin, good! thanks! Can we use `typedef`? Now I'm using a macro: `#define $new std::make_shared`

Comment: @Zach Typedefs are for types. This is a function template.

Comment: @Zach `typedef` is used to alias types. `std::make_shared` is not a type, it's a function template. The simplest approach is to wrap it in another function template with the name you want.